# Logical error-encrypting a message in C++

Tags: c++

the code should count each character. If the character is a number, it should count the previous character as much as the number.
So if the input is 'a', it should count 'a' once and assign it to acounter which now is equal to 1.
but if after 'a' is 3, it means 'aaa' and it should count 'a' three times and assign it to acounter which now is equal to 3.
Note: the program is for all of the alphabets but if this one isn't solved then what's the point of writing the rest?

I've tried put another loop exclusively for numbers but it didn't work.

```
char secret_message[1000];
    int counter,number_counter;
    int acounter=0;

    gets(secret_message);

    for (counter = 0 ; secret_message[counter] != NULL ; counter++)
    {
        if (secret_message[counter]=='a')
            acounter++;

        if (secret_message[counter] >= '0' && secret_message[counter] <= '9')
        {
            for(number_counter=1;number_counter<=secret_message[counter];number_counter++)
            {               
                if (secret_message[counter-1]=='a')
                    acounter++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<"acounter is:"<<acounter;
```

if the input is a3 the output should be 3, but it's 52 !

Comment: To convert a digit to the number that it represents, subtract `'0'`. That is, change `number_counter<= secret_message[counter]` to `number_counter<=secret_message[counter]-'0'`.

Comment: See [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), it could shorten your program.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text instead of character arrays.  Arrays can overflow.  The `std::string` takes care of resizing the text dynamically for you.

Comment: to @PeteBecker
thank you so much! it works
But could you please describe this '0' more? I've never heard of it

Comment: _"but it didn't work"_ Isn't an appropriate problem description. Be more specific please.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews , you're probably right but this is homework and we're not supposed to use functions.

Comment: `’0’` is the character that represents 0. The values of the characters that represent the digits 0..9 are required to be contiguous and increasing. As a r sult, if you have a `char` value that you know holds a character that represents a digit, you can get the value of that digit by subtracting `’0’`.

Comment: Since this is homework, you're not supposed to use StackOverflow, either :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to convert the digit from text to number, then use addition:

```
if (isdigit(secret_message[counter]))
{
    const int value = secret_message[counter] - '0';
    acounter += value;
}
```